# running spark aggregate funtion on rdd passing max as first function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double] = MapPartitionsRDD[14] at map at <console>:39
scala> r.aggregate(0)(math.max(_,_),_+_)
<console>:42: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: Int
              r.aggregate(0)(math.max(_,_),_+_)
                                        ^
```

I want to know what I am doing wrong as max function can be applied on double as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an `Int` as your seed, you need a `Double`:

```
r.aggregate(0D)(math.max(_,_), _+_)
```

Comment: Thanks for this I have checked doc now can you answer one more thing        
def aggregate[U: ClassTag](zeroValue: U)(seqOp: (U, T) => U, combOp: (U, U) => U): U    // why we need two functions for aggregate generally i have seen one  means same function can be applied to partition as well as the output of partition thats the image of aggragate in my mind

Comment: @vipin You need two functions because the first decides how values will be accumulated *inside* a partition, and the second decides how to combine the results from *different partitons*